# How to format SXA sitemap XML?

Tags: sxa, sitemap

I am getting `Sitemap XML` using `mydomain/sitemap.xml` but because of a tag, it is not correctly getting rendered in all browsers. Is there a way to configure/remove the following particular tag from `sitemap.xml`

Need to remove this:

`xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://mydomain.com/en`

[image]

Comment: Likely not worth the effort to change this. The goal is to have a file compatible with search engines.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can. But it's not configurable.

You need to override `SitemapGenerator` located in `Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata` library. Most of the things are marked there as protected virtual so you shouldn't have problems with achieving what you want in your implementation.

At the end just replace SXA implementation with your one in the DI container. This class is registered in the `Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.config` configuration file (section `<services>`) but you can replace it in the code as well.